# PHP/MySQL conventions when it comes to systemizing

Tags: php, mysql

Title doesn't make too much sense, but I will try to explain further.
I am currently making a website (a game), and I currently have different folders for users/ranks etc, each with their own config and class.****.php file.

I am new to PHP/MySQL and now it seems like having these functions seperately with their own config.php to connect to the database is not the greatest idea.

If I want to fetch, let's say, username and rank, then I could be object-oriented and have a getter for those in each class.****.php file, or I could fetch it inside the file required. However, that's gonna be a lot of "SELECT FROM" in each file, which seems pretty unecessary.

Is there a different approach that I haven't thought about, or should I have all the functions in one file?

Feel free to ask questions if I am too vague.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  might want to look at ORM frameworks. How do they work?
You fetch data in an OO way and get "entities"-rows which you can manipulate with your own functions. In some cases you may never have to write SQL. Here are some examples:

**General purpose /Light-weight/Simple:**

1. [RedBeanPHP](http://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php)
2. [IdiORM](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm)

**Advanced/Full-fledged/Feature-rich**

1. [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)
2. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html)

The list is *endless*. Just try each one of those and see what works for you

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed

Comment: Good just keep trying things and you'll know which one is best